# Use history.push in action creator with react-router-v4?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

The only working method that I found to work this out without using `react-router-redux` to route from `action creator async action` completion is by passing the `history` prop from the component to action creator and doing:

```
history.push('routename');
```

Since `BrowserRouter` ignores the history prop passed to it thus we cannot use custom history objects with browserhistory.

What is the best possible way to work this out?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of using `BrowserRouter` you could use the `Router` with custom history like

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'

import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

in which case your `history.push()` will work. With BrowserRouter `history.push` doesn't work because Creating a new `browserHistory` won't work because `<BrowserRouter>` creates its own history instance, and listens for changes on that. So a different instance will change the url but not update the `<BrowserRouter>`.

Once you create a custom `history`, you can export it and then import it in your `action creator` and use it to navigate dynamically like

```
import { history } from '/path/to/index';

const someAction = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        ApiCall().then((res) => {
            dispatch({type: 'SOME_CALL', payload: res })
            history.push('/home');
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `history` also contain the `location` (`history.location.pathname`), very useful to redirect base on current url.

Comment: With this solution, importing history object to action creator I'm getting an error `TypeError: "_routing__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.push is not a function"`

Comment: @ann.piv Are you sure you have exported history as a default

Comment: Yes it's default export. History object is imported in actions file, but I'm getting an error when calling history.push

Comment: @ann.piv Can you create a post with more details about its usage and creation

Comment: Here is the link to my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686352/react-redux-redirect-after-object-is-created-using-new-object-id-in-url

Comment: By using react-router's Router can we use Switch and Route from react-router-dom as it's child node?