# How to change Router from Action Creators with Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I decided to move all logic from React Components into Action Creators. In order to do this, I migrate classic Redux action creators to async Redux-Thunk action creators.

The basic flow works excellent. But I do not know how to update Router from the async Action Creators :(

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as dialogActions from './DialogActions';

export const login = (creds) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post('/admin/login', creds)
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers['authorization']);

        //Next line gives error
        this.props.history.push("/admin/home");

        dispatch(dialogActions.initErrorAction(false, ''));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
        dispatch(dialogActions.initErrorAction(true, 'Invalid email or password'));
      });
  }
}
```

So the question is: how to update Router from Redux-Thunk Action Creators?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514773/how-to-route-from-action-creator-after-successful-completion-of-async-call-in-re/48514877#48514877

Comment: Works! So this is the solution

Comment: Consider upvoting the answer if it helped