# Routing programmatically in react with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

Below code snippet from index.js works fine to me when I want to route from static links on the page-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h2>My Page</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to={'/'}>LoginForm</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={'/home'}>Home</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={LoginForm} />
          <Route exact path='/home' component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

Is there away to route into another page inside the code, like ?

```
 updateStore(loggedIn){
    const action = {type:loggedIn};
    store.dispatch(action);
    if(loggedIn==='LOGGED_IN'){
       console.log("I am In");
      //route me into another page ??
    }else{
      console.log("I am out");
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `Linking programmatically` ?

Comment: Similar to something Link to in <li><Link to={'/'}>LoginForm</Link></li>. I want to route in my callback method after successful login.

Comment: you want to redirect to `/` after login?

Comment: i want to redirect to /home after I login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514773/use-history-push-in-action-creator-with-react-router-v4)

Created my own route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import Home from './components/Home';

class RouteList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
                <Route path='/home' exact={true} component={Home}></Route>
            </Switch>

        );
    }
}

export default RouteList;
```

Then in index.js -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import RouteList from './route';
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
export const history = createBrowserHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <RouteList></RouteList>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And finally in my action.js -

```
import { history } from '../index';

callLoginApi(email, password, error => {
  dispatch(setLoginPending(false));
  if (!error) {
    dispatch(setLoginSuccess(true));
    history.push('/home');
  } else {
    dispatch(setLoginError(error));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) for that

> npm i react-router --save

in your component do the followings

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

 callback = () => {
   browserHistory.push('/home');
 }
```

Comment: this is not working :( .. I am using "import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';" in index.js. May be react-router-dom is different from react-router

Comment: have a look at this answer regarding you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684809/react-router-vs-react-router-dom-when-to-use-one-or-the-other