# React, Redux - redirect after object is created (using new object id in URL)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router-dom

I think I have a quite common problem, but can't find up to date answer that I would be sure is good practice.

I'm writing a forum app using React, Redux, React Router DOM. I'm using BrowserRouter.

Here is what I want to do: after I post a request to create a thread and it is fulfilled, I want to redirect user to newly created thread page (I need object id that I will get in response for URL).

*component*

```
class CreateThread extends React.Component {

  handleCreateThread = (values) => {
    this.props.createThread(values);

  [...more code...]
}
```

*actions*

```
export const createThread = (data) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await instance().post('/api/threads/', data);
    // const { id, category } = response.data;
    // history.push(`/categories/${category.id}/threads/${id}`);
    dispatch({ type: types.CREATE_THREAD_FULFILLED, payload: response.data })
  } catch(err) {
    dispatch({ type: types.CREATE_THREAD_ERRORS, payload: err.response.data })
  }
};
```

What is the best way to do it? I think it would be easiest to redirect inside actions. Is it good practice? How can I access history object in this case? 
(The commented part in the code in actions does not work, I can't access history object like that).
I was searching for an answer but I found many that are not up-to-date or contradictory and I'm very confused.

------------EDIT----------

So I have followed an advice of Ahmad Nawaz Khan, but when trying to access history.push inside action creator I'm getting an error `TypeError: "_routing__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.push is not a function"`

```
// routing/history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();

// routing/index.js
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

const Routing = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      ...

// redux/actions/index.js
import history from '../../routing';

export const createThread = (data) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await instance().post('/api/threads/', data);    
    const { id, category } = response.data;
    history.push(`/categories/${category.id}/threads/${id}`);
    dispatch({ type: types.CREATE_THREAD_FULFILLED, payload: response.data })
  } catch(err) {
    ...
```

"history": "^4.10.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react": "^16.12.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a custom history object then you cannot use BrowserRouter, you have to use Router instead, which works similar to the BrowerRouter except that it takes custom a history object.

create a history object (if not created)

```
//history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Change BrowerRouter to Router

```
import Router from "react-router-dom";
```

Import and pass the history object to the Router (history.push wouldn't work if you haven't passed the history object to the router.)

```
import history from "./history.js"
...
<Router history={history}>
```

Now you can either redirect a user from the action creator or CreateThread component.
And yes it's a good practice to redirect a user from action creator but if you want to do that from CreateThread component then you would have to return a promise from the createThread action creator.

Comment: Very direct and clear answer, thank you. Unfortunatelly when I import history to my actions, I'm getting an error when calling history push. I have no access to push method `_routing__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.push is not a function`. With what you said I can access history in my component. I can pass history as an argument in handler, but I could do it also with BrowserRouter. This way it works for me, but probably not the most beautiful solution..

Comment: I don't think the code has a problem, maybe the webpack isn't working properly. Which version of the react-router are you using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2". I think you are right.. but I don't know how to get rid of that error. I think I will just stick with passing the history as argument to action creator as this solution is working for me..

Answer (score 2):

History.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory';
export default createHistory()
```

Action.js

```
import history from './history'
history.push('/send to my new page');
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your imports and your file usages I see that the problem here is just of an incorrect import.

You have defined history to be in `history.js` file however you try to import it from `routing/index.js` like

Update your import of history and it should work for you

```
// redux/actions/index.js
import history from '../../routing/history.js';

export const createThread = (data) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await instance().post('/api/threads/', data);    
    const { id, category } = response.data;
    history.push(`/categories/${category.id}/threads/${id}`);
    dispatch({ type: types.CREATE_THREAD_FULFILLED, payload: response.data })
  } catch(err) {
    ...
```

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and see if it solves your original issue instead of adding a workaround

Comment: So you were right! It works now! I'm surprised, I didn't expect it can be import error with this error message and overlooked it! Thanks a lot!