# React-Redux - How to redirect the page after storing the data in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying out a react-redux sample code where I would like to add a course in one form upon clicking 'Add Course', I want to update the store and redirect to a new page with the list of courses.

But for some reason, the redirect happen after calling the redux action creator. It stays in the same page.

Any ideas how to redirect the results to a different page?

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as courseActions from "../../redux/actions/courseActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import history from './history'


class CoursesPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    course: {
      title: "",
    },
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.actions.loadCourses.createCourse(this.state.course).then(() => {
      alert('Inside Promise') 
      history.push('/AllCourses'); //This doesn't get executed.
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h2>Courses</h2>
          <h3>Add Course</h3>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Course" />
          {this.props.courses.map((course) => (
            <div key={course.title}>{course.title}</div>
          ))}
        </form>
        <hr />
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CoursesPage.propTypes = {
  courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    courses: state.courses,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      loadCourses: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch),
    },
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoursesPage);


Action Code:

import * as types from "./actionTypes";

export function createCourse(course) {
  return { type: types.CREATE_COURSE, course };
}


Reducer:

import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";

export default function courseReducer(state = [], action) {
  debugger;
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_COURSE:
      return [...state, { ...action.course }];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

history.js

import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'

export default createHistory()
```

Comment: can you share `action code`

Comment: I just updated the code. Thanks

Comment: createCourse does not return any promise

Comment: you can simple do `this.props.actions.loadCourses.createCourse(this.state.course); history.push('/allCourses');`

Comment: Maybe this helps: [use `history.push()` in action creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514773/use-history-push-in-action-creator-with-react-router-v4).

Comment: @Srinvas where does `history` declared/imported?

Comment: The control doesn't come back. I added alerts after .createCourse() but they never got executed.

Comment: I created history.js and imported it in the page

Comment: Also action is not a promise, then will not be executed

Comment: I don't see it imported on CoursesPage

Comment: @Roy.B what is the best way to display the results in a new page after calling action? I updated the code just now.

Comment: This action dosent depends on api call, no need to wait for response, trigger the action and then push to new route. Remove the `then`

Comment: why not saving `const history = createHistory()`, and use `history.navigate`

Comment: @Roy.B It still doesn't redirect. not sure if it is understanding the path defined in App.js.   <Route path="/AllCourses" component={AllCourses} />

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom middleware to do so:

```
const hasAddedData = (state) => {
    // Your checks    
}

const redirectMiddleware = history => storeAPI => next => action => {
    console.log('dispatching', action)
    const result = next(action);
    // If the action is the one you want to trigger the redirect (action.type)
    // and the state pass the checks (storeAPI.getState()),
    // do the redirect.
    //
    // This would be like:
    if (action.type === types.CREATE_COURSE && hasAddedData(storeAPI.getState())) {
        history.push(destinationPath);
    }
    // You must return the result of next(action) to avoid breaking Redux.
    return result;
}
```

And wherever you create your Redux Store:

```
// history should already be provided by React Router.
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(redirectMiddleware(history))

const store = createStore(yourRootReducer, middlewareEnhancer)
```

If you need to check the previous state too, just set a const with storeAPI.getState() before running next(action). You can expand your middleware with other redirect checks or scenarios you need for additional actions.

**WARNING:** I wanted to give you the vanilla code solution, but keep in mind these three things:

- This is a task that is probably better and opinionatedly made by a library (check [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router)).
- Also, instead of making a custom middleware for action specific tasks, you can use a widely accepted middleware library such as [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/).
- Think about your app workflow. Do you need additional state properties (done flags, selection properties...)? Are all the CREATE_COURSE actions going to redirect or only a fraction of them? Will a specific REDIRECT action make things easier for you? Do you really need an imperative redirect or would it be possible, with the right state structure, a declararive Redirect with  React Router component?